# Unable to get file type for certain file

Tags: c#, wpf, file-type

As i am able get Correct file Type for image as JPEG Image. But i can get file type for pdf document or sql file.
I am using below code:

```
public String Type
{
      get
      {
            return GetType(Path.GetExtension(_document.DocumentPath));
      }
 }
public static string ReadDefaultValue(string regKey)
{
     using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(regKey, false))
     {
       if (key != null)
       {
           return key.GetValue("") as string;
       } 
     }
     return null;
}

public string GetType(string ext)
{
     if (ext.StartsWith(".") && ext.Length > 1) ext = ext.Substring(1);
     var retVal = ReadDefaultValue(ext + "file");
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal)) return retVal;

     using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("." + ext, false))
     {
        if (key == null) return "";
          using (var subkey = key.OpenSubKey("OpenWithProgids"))
          {
                    if (subkey == null) return "";

                    var names = subkey.GetValueNames();
                    if (names == null || names.Length == 0) return "";

                    foreach (var name in names)
                    {
                        retVal = ReadDefaultValue(name);
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal)) return retVal;
                    }
                }
            }

            return "";
        }
```

As i have seen that there is no "OpenWithProgids" subkey in .pdf file in regedit.
 so what can do to get these file types.

For Example
In win 7[image]

file type listed with file name and with other information ,
I want that same file type in my application 
I am able to xps document but not other document

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the extension of a file? For example:

`Filename.png` would return `.png`?

Comment: No i want that if file is .png then it return PNG Image like win 7

Comment: @khushbu, so...you if a file type is of .png, you want to display that image in your application?

Comment: @khushbu The value of the `(default)` subkey of the `HKCR\.pdf` on my box has the value `AcroExch.Document`. In turn `HKCR\AcroExch.Document\(default)` says "Adobe Acrobat Document". No need to even go into an `OpenWithProgIds` subkey. However, I'm not sure that this is the right way to figure the "file type name" in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can get type using windows API [SHGetFileInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetFileInfo.html) function

```
        [Flags]
        private enum SHGFI : int
        {
            /// <summary>get type name</summary>
            TypeName = 0x000000400,
        }

        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi,
            uint cbFileInfo, uint uFlags);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct SHFILEINFO
        {
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public int iIcon;
            public uint dwAttributes;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)] public string szDisplayName;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)] public string szTypeName;
        };

        private static void Main()
        {
            SHGFI flags = SHGFI.TypeName;
            SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
           SHGetFileInfo(your path, 0,
                ref shinfo, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),(uint) flags);

            Console.WriteLine(shinfo.szTypeName);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: this gives me exception as The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x656ee556, on thread 0xac. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Comment: I had never got this error before I'm using both Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 and it works correctly with no errors

Comment: Could the errors occurs because of this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72238339-3b16-4d09-93ee-e84401e6681b/native-exception-excpetion-code-0xc0000005

Comment: Now its suddenly shut down my application due to error

Comment: could you post the rest of your code could the problem somewhere else